# how can I upload my game to Facebook Instant Games

Tags: html, facebook-instant-games

I am trying to upload my first demo app to Facebook instant games. Unfortunately it's been a while since I properly coded on HTML5 but I just want to make sure that my demo app works on Facebook instant games. But when I try to upload my file it keeps giving errors on facebook. like

> > Games must reference one of our supported SDKs via our CDN.

and others. I tried to edit some basic things according to some tutorials but I didn't get any luck. So I am uploading my whole file here and I hope you can tell me what lines should I add in order to be able to upload on Facebook instant games with no problem. thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name = "viewpoint" content="width=device-width, inital-scale = 1.0">
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div id="quiz">

            <audio  autoplay="true" loop="true" >
                <source src="bg-music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"  >
           </audio>
            <p id="question"></p>

            <div class="buttons">
                <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
                <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>
                <button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
                <button id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></button>
            </div>

               <!--  <progress value="12" max="15" id="progress"></progress> -->    

        </div>
    </div>

<script src="quiz.js"></script>
<script src="question.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

please tell me if I need to create a new folder and/or if I need to add new lines. Ask me if you have any additional questions. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You must refer following page.
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/getting-started/quickstart)

1) Import facebook-instant-game sdk.

2) Include fbapp-config.json in your zip. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/sdk/bundle-config/)

3) Upload in you App dashboard.